# Deriving a Kalman Filter Equation for a Linear Gaussian Filtering Model with Non Zero Mean Noise

Tags: kalman-filters, filtering, smoothing, bayesian-estimation

I am trying to answer an exercise question from the book [Simo Sarkka - Bayesian Filtering and Smoothing](https://users.aalto.fi/%7Essarkka/pub/cup_book_online_20131111.pdf).

The question is:

[image]

Does anyone know if there is a resource that has the solutions for this book?

Comment: Welcome to our community. Please don't link using `This Book`, `This Link`, etc... One day the links won't be available. Hence write the full name of what you link for so in case the link isn't working, people will be able to search for it.

Comment: Any chance you mark my answer or say what's missing? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Since the model is linear taking care of known mean is pretty simple.

### Measurement

Since the "Bias" of the measurement is known all you need is to define $ \hat{y}_{k} = {y}_{k} - {m}_{r} $. Then use it as you'd use a measurement with no bias.

### Model

The model is used in the prediction step. What you should do is use the regular prediction step and add to it $ {m}_{q} $ after the prediction.

All other steps only include the covariance matrices and are the same.